# How do I reattach a SubZero refrigerator door handle?

Tags: refrigerator

The handle on my SubZero refrigerator just came off. The "thing" that's attached to the door is fairly stiff and I haven't been able to unscrew it yet. Inside the hole in the "shim" that attaches to the handle is a star screw that holds the shim to the handle. Any idea how I would reattach this handle to the fridge?

[image]

Comment: Including the model number will get you the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a small set screw on the inside of the handle (opposite side of the picture). This is usually driven with a small Allen key.  Loosen the screw, place the handle back on flush against the door surface, and tighten the screw finger-tight. Don't over tighten as they strip easily because they are so small.

The screw will look something like this

[image: Set screw]
<sub>(source: [funrcboats.com](http://www.funrcboats.com/images/products/setscrew_md.jpg))</sub>

There might be a small plastic cap over the set screw in order to better hide it.

Comment: Turned out that the set screw was under the shim - in case anyone else comes across this answer and needs to find it.

Comment: What size is this set screw, need to find the right Allen for it.

Comment: They come in a variety of sizes.

Comment: A 3/32 allen wrench worked on my box. It's a 2006

Comment: A 3/32 Allen wrench worked for mine as well, with a #10 - 32 x 1/4 inch socket screw